# Add/Remove class on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have a dropdown Menu opening on click and when the font-awesome fa-bars icon is clicked the fa-bars class is removed and then the font-awesome fa-times class is added.

I also have a mouseleave function that closes the dropdown container when your mouse exits. My question is to see if I can have the icon class change from fa-times to fa-bars on mouseleave.

This is the code that changes the icon on click

```
 <a href="" class="btn megaNavBtn1" role="button"><i id="toggleMega" class="fa fa-bars megaNavIcon"></i></a>    

  $('#toggleMega').click(function(){
  var ele = $('.megaNavIcon');
   if(ele.hasClass('fa-bars')){
  ele.removeClass('fa-bars')
     .addClass('fa-times')
   }
   else{
  ele.addClass('fa-bars')
     .removeClass('fa-times')
   }
  });
```

This is the code that closes the container on mouseleave

```
$('.megaNav').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(".megaNav").collapse("hide");
});
```

Comment: After the `collapse` call, simply add/remove the respective class, just like in the first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the the `removeClass()` and `addClass()` methods inside your `mouseleave` function like this:

```
$('.megaNav').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(".megaNav").collapse("hide");
  $('#toggleMega').removeClass('fa-times');
  $('#toggleMega').addClass('fa-bars');
});
```

Or you can simplify this further by using the [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method like this:

```
$('.megaNav').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(".megaNav").collapse("hide");

  $('#toggleMega').toggleClass(function(){
    return $(this).hasClass('fa-times') ? 'fa-bars' : '';
  });
});
```

Comment: sometimes my brain forgets to think... thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane Answer updated. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

CSS should be your first choice for UI/layout functionality. A simple `.myclass:hover{}` rule is a super easy way to highlight items on `mouseenter` `mouseleave` events.

```css
li:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
<li>Bar</li>
<li>Boo</li>
<li>Yah</li>
<ul>
```